# Copying data from cells into cells of a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Im having problems copying the data from wstScanSheet into wstScanReport.
It keeps giving me a subscript, out of range error.

The second array I made, strReportArray2(), is what's giving me trouble.

This is the code:

```
Sub ImportReports()

'Report Arrays
Dim strReportArray() As String
Dim strReportArray2() As String

'Data being grabbed
Dim strDesc As String
Dim strPtNum As String
Dim strPartNo As String
Dim strSU As String
Dim strExpectQuantity As String
Dim strShipper As String
Dim strHtsCode As String
Dim strCOO As String
Dim strItemWeight As String
Dim strPrice As String
Dim strMOD As String
Dim strDealer As String
Dim strPDC As String
Dim strWTF As String
Dim strScanQuantity As String
Dim strRemain As String
Dim strStatus As String
Dim strAuditor As String
Dim strWeightUpdate As String
Dim strCOO_Num As String
Dim strSpecial As String
Dim strScale As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPickTicket As String
Dim strScanCOO As String

'Workbooks
Dim wbkReportBook As Workbook
Dim wbkBaseBook As Workbook

'Worksheets
Dim wstSUData As Worksheet
Dim wstScanSheet As Worksheet
Dim wstScanReport As Worksheet
Dim wstSuReport As Worksheet

'Counters
Dim lngBaseRow As Long
Dim lngReportRow As Long
Dim lngLineNum As Long
Dim varWeek As Variant
Dim datDate As Date
Dim dblDate As Double

'Data Pull
Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim varFile As Variant






'* Fill in strPath.

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "documents"
    If .Show = True Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'* Add a slash if the user forgot it.

If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strPath = strPath & "\"
End If

'* Set a few variables.

Set wbkBaseBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wstSuReport = wbkBaseBook.Sheets("SU Report")
Set wstScanReport = wbkBaseBook.Sheets("Scan Report")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False



'* Report work begins here.

RecursiveDir colFiles, strPath, "*_*_*_*.xlsm", True

For Each varFile In colFiles
    Set wbkReportBook = Workbooks.Open(varFile)
    Set wstSUData = wbkReportBook.Sheets("SUData")
    Set wstScanSheet = wbkReportBook.Sheets("Scan Sheet")



'* Preserve report data from SUData.

    'counter set
    lngLineNum = 0
    lngReportRow = 8

    'check to see if there is data
    Do While wstSUData.Cells(lngReportRow, 1) <> ""

        'store cell data into variables
            With wstSUData
                strPtNum = .Cells(lngReportRow, 1)
                strPartNo = .Cells(lngReportRow, 2)
                strSU = .Cells(lngReportRow, 3)
                strQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 4)
                strShipper = .Cells(lngReportRow, 5)
                strHtsCode = .Cells(lngReportRow, 6)
                strCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 7)
                strItemWeight = .Cells(lngReportRow, 8)
                strPrice = .Cells(lngReportRow, 9)
                strMOD = .Cells(lngReportRow, 10)
                strDealer = .Cells(lngReportRow, 11)
                strDesc = .Cells(lngReportRow, 12)
                strPDC = .Cells(lngReportRow, 13)
                strScanQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 14)
                strRemain = .Cells(lngReportRow, 15)
                strStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 16)
                strAuditor = .Cells(lngReportRow, 17)
                strWeightUpdate = .Cells(lngReportRow, 18)
                strCOO_Num = .Cells(lngReportRow, 19)
                strSpecial = .Cells(lngReportRow, 20)
                strScale = .Cells(lngReportRow, 21)
                datDate = dateScrub(.Cells(5, 1))
            End With

            'convert date variable
            dblDate = CDbl(datDate)

            'next line
            lngLineNum = lngLineNum + 1

            'store variable into array
            ReDim Preserve strReportArray(27, lngLineNum)
                strReportArray(0, lngLineNum) = varFile
                strReportArray(1, lngLineNum) = strPtNum
                strReportArray(2, lngLineNum) = strPartNo
                strReportArray(3, lngLineNum) = strSU
                strReportArray(4, lngLineNum) = strExpectQuantity
                strReportArray(5, lngLineNum) = strShipper
                strReportArray(6, lngLineNum) = strHtsCode
                strReportArray(7, lngLineNum) = strCOO
                strReportArray(8, lngLineNum) = strItemWeight
                strReportArray(9, lngLineNum) = strPrice
                strReportArray(10, lngLineNum) = strMOD
                strReportArray(11, lngLineNum) = strDealer
                strReportArray(12, lngLineNum) = strPDC
                strReportArray(13, lngLineNum) = strWTF
                strReportArray(14, lngLineNum) = strScanQuantity
                strReportArray(15, lngLineNum) = strRemain
                strReportArray(16, lngLineNum) = strStatus
                strReportArray(17, lngLineNum) = strAuditor
                strReportArray(18, lngLineNum) = strWeightUpdate
                strReportArray(19, lngLineNum) = strCOO_Num
                strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) = strSpecial
                strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) = strScale
                strReportArray(22, lngLineNum) = dblDate
                strReportArray(23, lngLineNum) = 0
                strReportArray(24, lngLineNum) = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(varFile).DateLastModified
                strReportArray(25, lngLineNum) = ""
                strReportArray(26, lngLineNum) = ""

            'next row
            lngReportRow = lngReportRow + 1

    Loop



'* Preserve report data from Scan Sheet.

    'counter set
    lngReportRow = 9
    lngLineNum = 0

    'check to see if there is data
    Do While wstScanReport.Cells(lngReportRow, 1) <> ""

         'store cell data into variables
            With wstScanSheet
                strPickTicket = .Cells(lngReportRow, 1)
                strScanCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 2)
                strPartNo = .Cells(lngReportRow, 3)
                strScanQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 4)
                strExpectQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 5)
                strRemain = .Cells(lngReportRow, 6)
                strSU = .Cells(lngReportRow, 7)
                strStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 8)
                strSystemCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 9)
                strCOOStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 10)
                strItemWeight = .Cells(lngReportRow, 11)
                strSpecial = .Cells(lngReportRow, 12)
                strScale = .Cells(lngReportRow, 13)
            End With

            'next line
            lngLineNum = lngLineNum + 1

            'store variables into array
            ReDim Preserve strReportArray2(13, lngLineNum)
            strReportArray2(0, lngLineNum) = strPickTicket
            strReportArray2(1, lngLineNum) = strScanCOO
            strReportArray2(2, lngLineNum) = strPartNo
            strReportArray2(3, lngLineNum) = strScanQuantity
            strReportArray2(4, lngLineNum) = strExpectQuantity
            strReportArray2(5, lngLineNum) = strRemain
            strReportArray2(6, lngLineNum) = strSU
            strReportArray2(7, lngLineNum) = strStatus
            strReportArray2(8, lngLineNum) = strSystemCOO
            strReportArray2(9, lngLineNum) = strCOOStatus
            strReportArray2(10, lngLineNum) = strItemWeight
            strReportArray2(11, lngLineNum) = strSpecial
            strReportArray2(12, lngLineNum) = strScale

        'next row
        lngReportRow = lngReportRow + 1

    Loop



'* Report work ends here.

wbkReportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next varFile

'* Paste the data into Su Report

'set counter
lngBaseRow = 2

'check if there is data
Do While wstSuReport.Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) <> ""
    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1
Loop

'for the first line til number of lines in strReportArray
For lngLineNum = 1 To UBound(strReportArray, 2)

    'calculates week
    varWeek = strReportArray(22, lngLineNum)
    Do Until Weekday(varWeek, vbSunday) = 2
        varWeek = varWeek - 1
    Loop

    'pastes data into SU Report
    With wstSuReport
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) = varWeek
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 2) = strReportArray(22, lngLineNum) 'date
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 3) = strReportArray(12, lngLineNum) 'depot
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 4) = strReportArray(11, lngLineNum) 'dealer
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 5) = strReportArray(10, lngLineNum) 'mod
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 6) = strReportArray(5, lngLineNum) 'shipper
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 7) = strReportArray(1, lngLineNum) 'ticket
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 8) = strReportArray(2, lngLineNum) 'part
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 9) = strReportArray(14, lngLineNum) 'scanned
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 10) = strReportArray(4, lngLineNum) 'expected
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 11) = strReportArray(15, lngLineNum) 'remain
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 12) = strReportArray(3, lngLineNum) 'su
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 13) = strReportArray(16, lngLineNum) 'status
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 14) = strReportArray(17, lngLineNum) 'auditor
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 15) = strReportArray(18, lngLineNum) 'weight update
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 16) = strReportArray(7, lngLineNum) 'coo
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 17) = strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) 'special
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 18) = strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) 'scale
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 19) = strReportArray(25, lngLineNum) 'system coo
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 20) = strReportArray(26, lngLineNum) 'coo status
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 21) = strReportArray(8, lngLineNum) 'part weight
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 22) = strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) 'spec process
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 23) = strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) 'scale count
    End With

    'next row in worksheet
    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1

'next line in array
Next lngLineNum

'* Paste the data into Scan Report

'set counter
lngBaseRow = 2

'check if there is data
Do While wstScanReport.Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) <> ""
    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1
Loop



'for the first line til number of lines in strReportArray
For lngLineNum = 1 To UBound(strReportArray2, 2)

'pastes data into Scan Report
    With wstScanReport
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) = strReportArray2(1, lngLineNum) 'pick ticket
    End With

    'next row in worksheet
    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1

'next line in array
Next lngLineNum

End Sub
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: yes i did.  its not a duplicate.  explain how? because i am not resizing the first dimension so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: thats a totally new array.  strReportArray is not strReportArray2

Comment: if you're just going to edit and not read my code then thats just abuse of  power, no offense.

Comment: That's fine.  I am just trying to figure this out, I been working on it all day.  The line of error where the runtime error 9 occurs is "For lngLineNum = 1 To UBound(strReportArray2, 2)".  Sorry, VBA doesnt give me a line number.

Comment: Please see this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I actually found out lngLineNum is not being incremented in the second loop, during a debug.  Does anyone know why this could be?  That could be my problem because I am trying to paste something that is only holding data in one column.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your arrays properly

```
Dim strReportArray2(,) As String    ' or better  Dim strReportArray2(1,1) As String
```

Add `Option Explicit` in the first line of the file

[image]

Then click Debug > Compile VBAProject to check for other errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already suggested this in another thread, but seeing the same code over and over is making me feel bad...

Create a mapping table which related "source" and "destination" column numbers for each "mapping type":

[image]

Then do something like this (untested):

```
Sub DoImport()

    Dim baseWB, shtR1, shtR2, rwR1, rwR2, m1, m2, e
    Dim wbIn, rwIn

    Set baseWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set shtR1 = baseWB.Sheets("Summary1")
    Set shtR2 = baseWB.Sheets("Summary2")
    Set rwR1 = shtR1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Set rwR2 = shtR2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

    Set m1 = Mapping("SUData")
    Set m2 = Mapping("ScanReport")


    Set wbIn = Workbooks.Open("pathHere")

    Set rwIn = wbIn.Sheets("SUData").Rows(8)
    Do While Application.CountA(rwIn) > 0

        MapRowData rwIn, rwR1, m1

        '*******************************
        'add in any additional data here
        '*******************************

        Set rwR1 = rwR1.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rwIn = rwIn.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Set rwIn = wbIn.Sheets("ScanData").Rows(8)
    Do While Application.CountA(rwIn) > 0

        MapRowData rwIn, rwR2, m2

        '*******************************
        'add in any additional data here
        '*******************************

        Set rwR2 = rwR2.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rwIn = rwIn.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub

Sub MapRowData(rwSrc, rwDest, map As Collection)
    Dim e
    For Each e In map
        rsdest.Cells(e(1)).Value = rwSrc.Cells(e(0)).Value
    Next e
End Sub


'get column mappings
Function Mapping(sType As String) As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection, c As Range
    Set c = Sheets("mapping").Range("A2")
    Do While c.Value <> ""
        If c.Value = sType Then
            col.Add Array(c.Offset(0, 1), c.Offset(0, 2))
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set Mapping = col
End Function
```

Once you get that working you'll be in a much better place ;-)

Comment: what are the offsets for?